# is it possible to do full-index table using ef core and migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, full-text-search, entity-framework-migrations

I need to do full-text search using EF Core.

I know that in EF Core we have EF.Functions.FreeText and it works fine as full-text search:

`var result = _db.Files.Where(c => EF.Functions.FreeText(c.Content, "Microsoft"));`

But only for full-indexed table. And i need to do full-index table using ef-core migrations. Is it possible? Or i need to use ado.net for full index? 
any help would be helpful!